Web driver manager with Chrome driver not working
I am trying to use Web driver manager and chrome driver. My project is Apache Ant based so I included all selenium chrome driver jar files and web driver manager jar file. Now I am writing this simple code:
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://selenium.dev");

    driver.quit();

and it is still giving following error:
error: cannot access ChromiumDriver
    [javac]         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac]   class file for org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver not found

I am using JDK16, and the code is in main method.

Something isn't installed or referenced correctly
